# Changing binary characters in string

Tags: python

I would like to convert this list:

```
a = [['0001', '0101'], ['1100', '0011']]
```

to:

```
a' = [['1110', '1010'],['0011','1100']]
```

In the second example, every character is changed to its opposite (i.e. '1' is changed to '0' and '0' is changed to '1').
The code I have tried is:

```
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        s=list(j)
        for k in s:
            position = s.index(k)
            if k=='0':
                s[position] = '1'
            elif k=='1':
                s[position] = '0'
        ''.join(s)
```

But it doen't work properly. What can I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function that flips the bits like this:

```
from string import maketrans

flip_table = maketrans('01', '10')
def flip(s):
    return s.translate(flip_table)
```

Then just call it on each item in the list like this:

```
>>> flip('1100')
'0011'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple list comprehension:

```
[[k.translate({48:'1', 49:'0'}) for k in i] for i in a]
```

`48` is the code for `"0"`, and `49` is the code for `"1"`.

Demo:

```
>>> a = [['0001', '0101'], ['1100', '0011']]
>>> [[k.translate({48:'1', 49:'0'}) for k in i] for i in a]
[['1110', '1010'], ['0011', '1100']]
```

For Python 2.x:

```
from string import translate, maketrans
[[translate(k, maketrans('10', '01')) for k in i] for i in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[["".join([str(int(not int(t))) for t in x]) for x in d] for d in a]
```

Example:

```
>>> a = [['0001', '0101'], ['1100', '0011']]
>>> a_ = [["".join([str(int(not int(t))) for t in x]) for x in d] for d in a]
>>> a_
[['1110', '1010'], ['0011', '1100']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from ast import literal_eval
import re

a = [['0001', '0101'], ['1100', '0011']]

print literal_eval(re.sub('[01]',lambda m: '0' if m.group()=='1' else '1',str(a)))
```

literal_eval() is said to be safer than eval()